# Error stating that CR_CONSUMER_INFO_selectchanges already exists?

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I am recently started working on Microsoft Sync framework 2.1 based project, which already developed, requirement is simple to sync db(server to client and client to server), but  i am getting very frequent error stating blah_blah_selectchanges already exist(procedure), once i will delete all mentioned procedure it will work fine.. then again when i am trying with another machine this error comes again.. Now i am not getting a idea how to overcome with this error... I did some research and found additional tables(under sync db) created by the provisioning process: Products_Tracking, schema_info, scope_config, and scope_info. There are also other database objects such as triggers and stored procedures created by the provisioning process. I have one doubt if additional table/Procedure/Triggers is already exist on sync schema why it is creating again..

Comment: Can _you_ read what you wrote? Because I can't. Could you format that a bit better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check how you're provisioning. Are you checking if the scope exists already? if there are existing scopes for the table and you want to add a new scope, you should specify SetCreateProceduresForAdditionalScopeDefault.